# Spring Security not Intercepting

Tags: java, spring-mvc, spring-security

When running the application it behaves as if there is no filter and I can access all pages as usual.

Web.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:web="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd" id="WebApp_ID" version="2.5">
  <display-name>SpringMVCTest</display-name>

    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>springMVCTest</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>

    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>springMVCTest</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>

    <filter>
        <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
        <filter-class>org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy</filter-class>
    </filter>


    <listener>
        <listener-class>
            org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener
        </listener-class>
    </listener>

    <context-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>/WEB-INF/springMVCTest-security.xml</param-value>
    </context-param>



</web-app>
```

springMVCTest-Security.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans:beans xmlns:beans="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.1.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/security 
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/spring-security-3.1.xsd">

    <http auto-config="true">
        <intercept-url pattern="/**" access="ROLE_ADMIN" />
    </http>

    <authentication-manager>
        <authentication-provider>
            <user-service id="userService">
                <user name="admin" password="admin" authorities="ROLE_ADMIN" />
            </user-service>
        </authentication-provider>
    </authentication-manager>
</beans:beans>
```

As all the configuration is in theses files I've only posted them to try and keep things simple. I'm assuming the problem must be in one of these two.

Comment: Maybe it is just a typo, but at a first look I read in web.xml you are looking for `springMVCTest-security.xml`, while the file name is springMVCTest-Security.xml, with a capital **S**

Comment: Aren't you missing a `filter-mapping` in `servlet.xml`?

Comment: got excited about the S, but it was just a typo.

Comment: Put a breakpoint anywhere in your code and check the stack.  Is the SpringSecurityFilterChain in the stack?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your spring security filter is not mapped to any URL. Just add a mapping to your web.xml:

```
<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>
```

Comment: I noticed this , however I'm working mainly from Spring in Action which makes no mention of using a filter mapping, so I was just assuming it defaulted to this same url if no mapping was supplied. Either way it behaves in the same way with or without it.

Comment: It started to suddenly work after stopping and starting the sever a few times with the filter mapping in. I guess it was the filter mapping after all.